# Why does cable length matter so much when source is high impedance?

Tags: impedance, microphone, signal-integrity

My beginner’s electronics book has now started to teach me about microphones, specifically Electret microphones.

While searching the web for more info, I stumbled upon an article where the author mentioned that when a microphone has high impedance it is critical to keep the cables connected to the microphone as short as possible or else the signal would degrade significantly.

I have been trying to make sense of such statement but so far I have failed miserably. No matter how I think about this I can’t imagine why a cable with such small impedance compared to a microphone’s huge impedance would matter at all.

Could someone please help me undestand this phenomenon?

In case it helps, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6McmnSmiY5o&feature=youtu.be&t=52s) is a link to the YouTube video where this is mentioned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the cable's capacitance, which is proportional to its length. This capacitance works in conjunction with the high source impedance of the microphone to create a low-pass filter that can severely attenuate the higher frequencies that you're interested in.

For example, if your microphone has a 100K output impedance, and your cable has 1000 pF of capacitance, together they create an R-C time constant of 100 µs, which corresponds to a cutoff frequency of about 15 kHz. Anything above this frequency will be attenuated at a rate of 6 dB/octave. Longer cables mean more capacitance, reducing the cutoff frequency proportionally.

Comment: I expect noise coupling is another reason to keep the leads on a high-impedance microphone short.

Comment: @Dave Tweed How do you infer the time constant from the impedance values ; and subsequently the cutoff frequency and attenuation from the value of the time constant?

Comment: @K.Rmth $$Z_0=\sqrt\frac{L}{C}$$ This is ofcoruce for losless line where L and C are both expressed as F/m and H/m - distributed capacitance/inductance.